# I am not sure if I could use the alternative words in these context

Tags: synonyms

So you've probably studied both of these movements... separately, separate **movements** . . . Realism and Impressionism in some of your art history courses, so who can just sum these up?

could replace movements with campains？

What's the difference between,  difference and differential used as a noun.（difference VS differential）

Pretty quickly though, thankfully, everybody realized the music should **suit** the film.（could I use 'match' to replace 'suit'.）

Yeah, original music scores weren't **common** then.(common VS popular,dominant)

But that all changed with the **introduction** of sound-on-film technology.(introduction VS emergence)

Actually, even before that- organs could **mimic** a number of instruments and also do some sound effects, so they were starting to replace live orchestras in some movie theaters.(VS simulate)

So you've probably studied both of these **movements**... separately, separate movements . . . Realism and Impressionism in some of your art history courses, so who can just sum these up?(VS campain)

Purposely fly there just to collect data? **Impressive**(VS admirable)

Is it art, or is it a method of **reproducing** images? Do photographs belong in museums or just in our homes?(VS replicating)

Comment: You need to ask a *single*, well-researched question, with enough information that it can be understood and answered objectively. I suggest editing the question and focusing only on one of the sentences, expanding it to provide definitions and why you think one word should be picked over another.

Comment: The problem is I could only ask only one question in every 40 mins.

Comment: I concur with Jason. Edit this with a numbered list of points you would like explained. But first, cut the number down to no more than *four* or they will bounce the question. I look forward to helping.

Comment: @梁耀文 By asking multiple question in one, you run the risk of getting no answer at all, or having the question closed. I disagree with the previous comment, by the way. Only if you have a single question that is *demonstrated* by several examples should you provide a list of items. (In fact, that type of list is fine.) But you shouldn't ask two different questions at once. If you want more than one thing explained, just pick one—and wait to ask a different question for the next.

Comment: In any case, as a learner of English as a foreign language, you should probably be asking questions on English Language Learners. Have you read the objectives of this site?